# Append span to h2 elements

Tags: javascript, append, blogger

Hy,
I would like to add a opening span tag after h2 elements, and a closing /span before the closing  element.
Like this:

```
<h2><data:title/></h2>
```

to

```
<h2><span><data:title/></span></h2>
```

via script, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Have you made any attempt? Where did you get stuck? What do you need us to help with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its pretty possible.
But its suggested to set an id for span you create so that you can add custom functionality via css or java script to it later on.

Simply write this way :

```
<h2><span id="give_some_name"><data:title/></span></h2>
```